# Find first unused ID with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table with the following structure:

`id, A, B, C, D, ...`

where A, B, C, D, ... are some columns.

Is there a way to select the first unused id where some of the columns are equal to a certain value?

For example, I have the following data:

```
 id  A  B  C  D
----------------
 1   1  1  1  1
 1   3  9  1  4
 2   3  2  1  0
 5   3  1  1  8
 1   2  5  4  2
```

and I want to select the first unused id where `A=3` and `C=1`.

So I want to consider only the middle 3 rows (as they have A=3 and C=1) and return `3` as a result (as it is the first unused id from the 1, 2, 5 ids).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either as @Gordon Linoff showed, or, alternatively, via variables:

```
SET @i=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM test WHERE A=3 AND C=1);
SELECT 
  id+1 AS first_unused 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
      id, 
      @i:=@i+1 AS seq 
  FROM test 
  WHERE 
    A=3 AND C=1
  ) AS sequence 
WHERE id+1=seq 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

this will work even if your ids do not start from 1

Comment: Thanks! It was important for me to work even if the ids do not start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using "not exists":

```
select t.*
from t
where A = 3 and C = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.A = 3 and t2.C = 1 and
                        t2.id = t.id + 1
                 );
```

Note that this will not find "1" if your ids start with "2".  This finds the first id following a used one.

Answer (score 0):

Should be working fine:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.unused_id)
FROM (
    SELECT *, id+1 AS unused_id
    FROM table1
    WHERE A = 3 AND C = 1
    ) AS t1
WHERE 
    t1.unused_id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        WHERE A = 3 AND C = 1
    )
```

And as other said it will not find 1 if ids will start from higher number, but you can easily checks if MIN(id) is not 1, and in that case return 1.

Answer (score 0):

this answer uses only one query and the php is doing the rest

```
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT(id) 
    FROM t
    WHERE A = 3
    AND C = 1
    ORDER BY id ASC
    ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query); 
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $rows[] = $row['id']; 
}

//rows = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 )
$counter = 1;

foreach($rows as $i){
    if($i == $counter){
        $counter ++;
        continue;
    }
    print_r($counter);
    return;
}
print_r($counter);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a simple SQL query.

`Select newID FROM (Select id+1 newID FROM rand WHERE A=3 AND C=1) as newTable WHERE newID NOT IN (Select id newID FROM rand WHERE A=3 AND C=1) LIMIT 1`

However if you are using the id to identify rows uniquely, don't select the id manually. Use an auto incrementing column to determine the id to avoid a race condition.

EDIT: Sorry my bad. This new answer will collect the next number to each id and then check if that id is already used up. If you remove `LIMIT 1`, you can get all the ids that are available

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. This would return 6 for their sample data (max(id) equals 5), but the expected result is 3.